# How do i build a basic web crawler for wikipedia pages to gather links?

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler

I've been watching bucky roberts videos on python for beginners and I am trying to build a basic web crawler for wikipedia pages using the similar type of code in the videos.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main_page_spider(max_pages):
page_list={1: "Contents",
           2:"Overview",
           3:"Outlines",
           4:"Lists",
           5:"Portals",
           6:"Glossaries",
           7:"Categories",
           8:"Indices",
           9:"Reference",
           10:"Culture",
           11:"Geography",
           12:"Health",
           13:"History",
           14:"Mathematics",
           15:"Nature",
           16:"People",
           17:"Philosophy",
           18:"Religion",
           19:"Society",
           20:"Technology"}
    for page in range(1,max_pages+1):
        if page == 1:
            url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Contents"
        else:
             url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Contents/" + str(page_list[page])
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        divs = soup.find('div', {'class': "mw-body-content", 'id': "bodyContent"})

        for link in divs.findAll('a'):
            href = "https://en.wikipedia.org" + str(link.get("href"))
            get_link_data(href)
            print(href)

def get_link_data(link_url):
    source_code = requests.get(link_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    divs = soup.find('div',{'class': "mw-body-content", 'id': "bodyContent"})
    for link in divs.findAll('a'):
        link_href_data = link.get("href")
        print(link_href_data)

main_page_spider(3)
```

The problem is when I comment out the function call for `get_link_data()` the program works fine and I get all the links from the number of pages I defined.
But, when when I uncomment it the program gathers few links and gives me errors like

> socket.gaierror,urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError,urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError,requests.exceptions.ConnectionError

How do i fix this?

Comment: If this is not primarily about learning Python, could you not alternatively download the Wikipedia database and get all the information ready-made?

Answer (score 2):

Any time you're scraping you should introduce delays so as not to overwhelm the site's resources - or your own. Running your script with the `get_link_data` line commented out, as you describe, produces 2763 lines of output. That's 2763 URLs that you'll scrape as fast as possible. This will often trigger errors, either from the site throttling you or from your own network or your DNS servers getting clogged.

Add a delay before every call to `get_link_data` - I'd recommend at least one second. It will take a while, but remember - you're gathering data from a freely available resource. Don't abuse it.

You should also be more selective about what links you follow. Of the 2763 URLs output, there are only 2291 unique ones - that's almost five hundred pages you'll scrape twice. Keep track of the URLs you've already handled, and don't request them again.

You can refine this further - about 100 of the URLs contain fragments (the part after the `#`). When scraping like this, fragments should generally be ignored - they usually only direct the browser where to focus. If you remove the `#` and everything after it from each URL, you're left with 2189 unique pages.

Some of the links you're coming up with are malformed, too. They look like so:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org//en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Portal:Contents/Outlines/Society_and_social_sciences&action=edit
```

You'll probably want to fix those - and maybe skip "edit" links entirely.

Finally, even if you do all these things you'll probably run into some exceptions. The internet is a messy place :) So you'll want to include error handling. Something along these lines:

```
for link in divs.findAll('a'):
    href = "https://en.wikipedia.org" + str(link.get("href"))
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        get_link_data(href)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to get url {}\nError: {}".format(href, e.__class__.__name__)
```

```